# How to obtain GCP project name within SQL run against BigQuery from Composer Airflow

Tags: instance-variables, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I would like to write a query to be executed by Composer/Airflow (python BigQueryOperator referring to an SQL file) along the lines of

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM `{{ GCP_PROJECT }}.dataset.table` ...
```

I wish for the GCP project to be parametrised in the SQL so I can deploy the same SQL file in the productiond/development (prod/dev) environments and test in dev without attempting to query prod tables the dev environment does not have access to.

Is this something that would already be set up?

On this point I couldn't find any helpful examples in the [Composer guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#gcp_operators), apart from that [GCP_PROJECT is already reserved](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables), not sure how to pass an environment variable on to the templating anyway.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it myself, but I think something like that should work:

```
import os
dag = DAG(...)

def print_env_var():
    print(os.environ["GCP_PROJECT"])

print_context = PythonOperator(
    task_id="gcp_project",
    python_callable=print_env_var,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Based on Google documentation it's not recommended to use reserved environmental variables (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables#reserved_names):

> Cloud Composer uses these reserved names for variables that internal
> processes use. Do not refer to reserved names in your workflows.
> Variable values can change without notice.

I think better approach to handle staging/production environments is to set variables in Airflow itself and read them in the dag. Here's a great resource that goes into a lot of detail about Airflow variables.